# How to list the effective HTTP access rules in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot, and some of it's modules add its own endpoints and security configuration. I also have my own endpoints and a security configuration. As this setting are applied in a given order, some rules got overwritten.

**Is there an easy way to list the effective HttpSecurity in the application?**

The easiest way would be if there would be an actuator endpoint, an "extended version of" */mappings*, which would list the effective access rules for each mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You have the Option to use Spring Boot Actuator, see here http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready.html. You have to paste it in your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The Endpoints like **/autoconfig**, **/beans**, etc. might help you.

Another solution is to obtain the SecurityFilerChain:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    FilterChainProxy fcp = (FilterChainProxy) ctx.getBean("springSecurityFilterChain");
    // obtain information and log...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the actuator module, and also checked these endpoints. As you said, they *might* help... My question was if there is an *easy* way to get the effective security, and though I can probably figure out the effective security from these actuator calls, it's anything but easy.

Comment: @endrec you should really list in your question which are the options you've already tried and why they didn't suit you. "Easy way" is really subjective unless you tell us what you mean by it.

Comment: @s.kwiotek Thanks, that's still not the "easy" way I was looking for, but that is a start, though still needs an awful lot of work in the "obtain information" part. 
I'm looking for an "extended version of" */mappings*, which would list the effective access rules for each mapping.